# React Native get base64 from picked image in iOS

Tags: image, firebase, base64, react-native, photo

Having issues converting a picked photo to base64. Need it for Firebase.

This is the first attempt:

```
ImagePickerManager.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
    if (response.uri) {
        var uri = response.uri;

        ImageStore.getBase64ForTag(
            uri,
            function (imageData) {
                this.setState({
                    imageData: imageData,
                    eventImage: { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData, isStatic: true }
                });
            }.bind(this),
            function (error) { console.log('uri getBase64ForTag error', error);}
        );
```

Getting this error:

```
2016-06-08 19:08:47.980 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] 'uri getBase64ForTag error', { code: 'ERCTERRORDOMAIN0',
message: 'Invalid imageTag: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/{HASH 1}/Library/Caches/{HASH 2}.jpg',
nativeStackIOS: 
[ '0   Project                         0x00000001001841cc RCTJSErrorFromCodeMessageAndNSError + 148',
 '1   Project                         0x00000001001840f8 RCTJSErrorFromNSError + 264',
 '2   Project                         0x000000010011ede8 __41-[RCTModuleMethod processMethodSignature]_block_invoke_2.203 + 112',
 '3   Project                         0x00000001001e324c -[RCTImageStoreManager getBase64ForTag:successCallback:errorCallback:] + 304',
 '4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183004a60 <redacted> + 144',
 '5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182efc488 <redacted> + 284',
 '6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182f00db0 <redacted> + 60',
 '7   Project                         0x0000000100120928 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 1684',
 '8   Project                         0x000000010016d2bc -[RCTBatchedBridge _handleRequestNumber:moduleID:methodID:params:] + 712',
 '9   Project                         0x000000010016c1d4 __33-[RCTBatchedBridge handleBuffer:]_block_invoke.460 + 1232',
 '10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001006c5a7c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24',
 '11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001006c5a3c _dispatch_client_callout + 16',
 '12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001006d2554 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1036',
 '13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001006c972c _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464',
 '14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001006c5a3c _dispatch_client_callout + 16',
 '15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001006d4c9c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2344',
 '16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001006d4364 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132',
 '17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000182c61470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092',
 '18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000182c61020 start_wqthread + 4' ],
domain: 'RCTErrorDomain' }
```

---

Also tried this approach, with ReadImageData:

```
    ImagePickerManager.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
        if (response.uri) {
            var uri = response.uri;

            ReadImageData.readImage(
                uri,
                function (imageData) {
                    this.setState({
                        imageData: imageData,
                        eventImage: { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData, isStatic: true }
                    });
                }.bind(this)
                // function (error) { console.log('Event image getBase64ForTag error', error);}
            );
```

But got this error instead:

```
2016-06-08 22:42:28.368 Project[1647:630750] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182ffedb0 0x182663f80 0x182ee21a0 0x182eedc48 0x100089730 0x18cf437cc 0x100711a7c 0x100711a3c 0x100720c9c 0x100720364 0x182c61470 0x182c61020)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

---

What am I doing wrong? :)

Comment: Are you using this package? https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker

Comment: are you setting noData to true in your options? I believe that not setting it prevents the base64 from generating. I use this package, and at one time I was getting the raw image, though now I'm able to just use the path.

Comment: @BradBumbalough Tried it now, but it didn't fix it. I think the problem isn't the image picker, but ImageStore.getBase64ForTag or ReadImageData.readImage. The goal is to pick a photo, create two resized versions and upload the base64 of those to a server.

Comment: You're passing `response.uri` to the function.. shouldn't you be passing `response.data` instead?

Comment: @Brad No it only accepts an uri as the parameter. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-asset-library-to-base64